# Angular 8 How to read an Arabic characters number as a real integer to convert it into specific format using toLocaleString()

Tags: angular, integer, arabic, angular8, arabic-support

I need to convert english numbers (1234567890) to arabic:

```
 arabicNumbers = ['۰', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];
```

Which I was successful in doing it using:

```
  let chars = value.toString(10).split('');
  //console.log(chars)
  for(let i=0; i<chars.length; i++)
  {
    chars[i]=arabicNumbers[chars[i]]
  }
  value = chars.join('');
```

The final value should formatted the same as the English number. For example, if I have a value of 89000000 USD after using `toLocaleString('en-GB')` it will be:

> 89,000,000

But in arabic it stays :

> ٨٩۰۰۰۰۰۰

What I need is:

> ٨٩,۰۰۰,۰۰۰

I tried `charCodeAt()` but it reconvert it to English characters instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to convert chars to Arabic numbers just use:

```
let enNumber = 89000000;
console.log(enNumber.toLocaleString('fa-IR')); // ۸۹٬۰۰۰٬۰۰۰
```

Comment: Are persian and arabic numbers the same ?

Comment: your welcome, you can try your country sign instead of `fa-IR`, it will work too but i don't know your country sign so used Persian.